# namespacing javascript in user control

Tags: asp.net

I have created a jquery slider usercontrol in asp.net using jquery UI slider. The user control have some javascript functions to set the value of the slider when the textbox value changes in the main page. Everything works fine if I have only usercontrol. But if I have multiple user controls, I am not sure how to namespace the javascript so that it calls the function inside the specific user control.

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Comment: Could you post a (short) example of what it is you are doing?

Comment: I have a javascript function setSliderValue(newvalue) inside the usercontrol. From the textchange event on the page, I get the textvalue and call setSliderValue(newvalue) and it calls the javascript function. But if I have two user controls then both of them have the setSliderValue() function. so, when I call setSliderValue(newvalue), it calls the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest object orienting your code - something like this (Obviously this is only pseudocode...)

```
function Slider(parentElement, id){
   var element = ... // get / create your element here
   // attach appropriate event listeners here...
   element.onclick = function(){
       //event handling code...
   }
   this.setValue = function(value){
      // set value of element
   }
   this.getValue = function(){
       //get value of element
   }
}
var sliderA = new Slider(document.getElementById('anElement'));
var sliderB = new Slider(document.getElementById('anotherElement'));
```